# Select Distinct column and Another Column - Oracle Hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I need to select distinct id and also need another column

```
MyClass  class1 = new MyClass();    
Criteria criteria = new Criteria(MyClass.class);
    ProjectionList projList = Projections.projectionList();
            projList.add(Projections.property("col1"));
            projList.add(Projections.property("col2"));
            criteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(projList));
class1 = criteria.list();
```

What will be the return type of criteria.list()?
If i try to assign it to MyClass.class I get ClassCast Exception.
Please assist. How will I get both my columns?

Answer (score 0):

The result of `criteria.list()` must be a `List<Object[]>`, so:

```
List<Object[]> result = criteria.list();
for (Object[] row : result) {
    Object col1 = row[0];
    Object col2 = row[1];
}
```